# Gulp and LiveServer (VS Code extension) Issue (Saving twice)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, sass, gulp

I'm having an issue with Gulp and my VS Code extension - LiveServer

I have my Gulp tasks set up to compile my Sass, minify my CSS, then watch for changes.  The live reload is handled via an extension I mentioned above.  However, when I save none of my changes go live unless I save twice.

I suspect it's part of my Gulp tasks but couldn't fix it after working for about 30 mins.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  My Gulp tasks are below:

```
const cleanCSS = require("gulp-clean-css");
const sass = require("gulp-sass");

sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

function compileSass() {
  return gulp 
  .src('./assets/css/styles.scss')
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css'))
}

function minifyCSS() {
  return gulp
    .src("./assets/css/*.css")
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./assets/minified"));
}

gulp.task("compileSass", compileSass);
gulp.task("minify-css", minifyCSS);

gulp.task("watch", () => {
  gulp.watch("./assets/css/styles.scss", compileSass);
  gulp.watch("./assets/css/*.css", minifyCSS);
});

gulp.task("default", gulp.series("compileSass","minify-css", "watch"));
```

Comment: I see the last commit on Live Server was on 2/9/2019 and did update the chokidar dependency.  Are you using the latest version of Live Server - 5.4.0?

Comment: Apologies about the late response, but I did update to the latest version of LiveServer - I still have to save twice to get my changes to show though

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling Vscode and necessary extensions . Or
In Vscode select the option 'auto save' in File section . this will solve the issue of hitting save 2 times
and try installing live sass compiler which is from the creator of live server and it compiles sass to Css real time